How to Convert 16 bit to Decimal on Multisim?
I have created a Simple Calculator and I want to show the Output as Decimal Up to 65535. Output currently Showing as 1 0. Can anyone suggest me How can I do It Thanks

Are you saying that you have 16 bit binary data and you want to display it in base-10 format? If so, you may want to consider the double dabble method. Here's what it would look like for 16 bits.

Thank you very much, Are there any method than this? Something like BCD TO DECIMAL DECODER/DRIVERS component using? Or ADC 16 USING

Many of the same skills required for a calculator can be applied to solving the problem of binary to decimal conversion.
I will provide two completely different approaches, one combinatorial/combinational and one sequential. The combinational method derives from double dabble, discussed on Wikipedia. The sequential method derives from this approach discussed at Digikey's forum site.
double dabble
The method described on the wikipedia page, double dabble, can be implemented this way:

The above schematic is encapsulated within each of the yellow blocks labeled SADD3 below:

You may, of course, also simplify the three blue-circled SADD3 blocks with "0" at their \$A_3\$ input. But for demonstration purposes the above schematic just uses the block, repeatedly.
I didn't add 7-segment displays. But it is obvious how to hook up the outputs to a BCD-to-7-Seg decoder to achieve it. But if I do add such displays and plug in 0xFFFF as an input, this is what I'd get:

That's sufficient demonstration here.
sequential binary to BCD
There's adequate information here for a sequential approach to a 16-bit binary to BCD converter. The basic block in this case would be:

The above will become another yellow block below and called BCDSEQ, as applied here below:

This is just a parallel-load, serial-out 16 bit register (circled in blue) followed by five of the BCDSEQ units, with added displays above. (A pair of 74166 ICs would suffice for blue circled section.)
To operate it, set the data and cause CLR to go HI, pulse CLK, then drive CLR back LO. Then apply 16 pulses to CLK. Done.
It's possible, again, to optimize a little. The highest order BCDSEQ block doesn't require one of the D FFs (since the upper most digit cannot ever be larger than 6.) But again for demonstration purposes the above schematic just uses the block, repeatedly.
Here's the result when applying 0xBD98 and providing the clocking:

That's sufficient demonstration, again.
summary
The above are based upon two different ideas taken from two different sources, both easy to read about and use.

Thank you so much

@IvanSnow Please take good advantage of the time I offered and study these approaches. There are other methods as well so be open to expanding your imagination, too. Make the most of your gifts and do well for others who need you to help them, as well. Give back what you receive. We all need each other. We are family. Best wishes.
